Type Safety For Conditional Rendered Element
I am creating a custom button component, and based on the prop: link (boolean), I want to render a  component or a  component.
Since I'm working in typescript i had to type the props coming in. This is the best i could do after trying multiple things, but I cant help thinking theres a better way.
Please whats the best way to handle the type for ...props:

const Button = ({ link, className, ...props }: ButtonProps) => {
  return link ? (
    <Link className={cn(className)} {...(props as LinkProps)} />
  ) : (
    <button
      className={cn(className)}
      {...(props as ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>)}
    />
  );
};


I expected to simply type ButtonProps as LinkProps | ButtonHTMLAttributes,
but there were type conflicts, for obvious reasons.

See this
